# fetch & show images from database with break

Tags: php, mysql, image

If i ve inserted images in database in this format

[image]

But i want to show the results like this if i m selecting all the images at a time

```
<?php
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  portfolio");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
?>


<td><img src="portfolio/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height='100px' width='150px' /></a></td>
```

[image]

After 3 images it should take a break & show in another column ..

any help here.. thankss

Comment: Use **PDO** or **MySQLi** instead of **mysql_*** functions (depreciated).

Comment: First build your proper HTML, you only placed TD's but no TR's.

Comment: its for a cms panel actualy @RoyalBg i ve to show them at a time in single tr n td

Answer (score 1):

I certainly don't recommend you to use **mysql*** functions. Your **HTML** had errors too. Why is there "**a**" close tag when there is no opening tag of **a** ? I removed it from my answer. Also you didn't had any opeining **tr** tag or **table** tag. I added them to the answer.

```
<?php
echo"<table><tbody><tr>";
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  portfolio");
$k=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s)){
 $k++;
 if($k==4){
  echo"</tr><tr>";
  $k=0;
 }
?>
 <td><img src="portfolio/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height='100px' width='150px' /></td>
<?
}
echo"</tr></tbody></table>";
?>
```

Here's how you do it in **PDO** :

```
<?php
echo"<table><tbody><tr>";
$sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM  portfolio");
$sql->execute();
$k=0;
while($row=$sql->fetch()){
$k++;
if($k==4){
 echo"</tr><tr>";
 $k=0;
}
?>
<td><img src="portfolio/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height='100px' width='150px' /></td>
<?
}
echo"</tr></tbody></table>";
?>
```

Comment: let me try it first.. thanks for the response